# Does Numpy have an inbuilt elementwise matrix modular exponentiation implementation

Tags: numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

Does numpy have an inbuilt implementation for modular exponentation of matrices?

(As pointed out by user2357112, I am actually looking for element wise modular reduction)

One way modular exponentiation on regular numbers is done is with Exponentiation by Squaring (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), with a modular reduction taken at each step. I am wondering if there is a similar inbuilt solution for matrix multiplication. I am aware I can write code to emulate this easily, but I am wondering if there is an inbuilt solution.

Comment: I wasn't aware of any matrix modulus operation. Do you want an elementwise modulus? (Are you trying to perform matrix math in a finite field?)

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I was trying to do! Sorry I assumed matrix modulus meant element wise modulus

Comment: See https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8804

Comment: Thank you! Is there was a way to make your comment the accepted answer (or to otherwhise close the question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modular exponentiation is not currently built in NumPy ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8804)). The easiest/laziest way to achieve it is [frompyfunc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html#numpy.frompyfunc):

```
modexp = np.frompyfunc(pow, 3, 1)
print(modexp(np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]), 2, 3).astype(int))
```

prints

```
[[1 1]
 [0 1]]
```

This is of course slower than native NumPy would be, and we get an array with dtype=object (hence `astype(int)` is added).